# Add a column to Woocommerce order table as "Assigned" and hook it with a list of Editors from a drop down menu

Tags: woocommerce, view, roles

Sorry I am not a hardcore coder. Need to solve Three problems and need your help please.

1. I need to be able to assign an user (i.e Editor) to a job from Edit Order Page (from a list of Editors dropdown menu)
2. I would like to see which orders are assigned to whom from Oder Table view next to status column (Admin view)
3. Each editor should only see their assigned order when they login to wordpress using their login credential
   If anyone can provide the code or point me to a solution, I would really appreciate it.
   Zed

Comment: Most of the requirements can be fixed with a plugin that creates members or gives access to specific roles. If you have more context or what you are trying to achieve, then this would be more helpful. About 2 and 3 they both can be hard-coded using some filters, but surely it needs more context.